# Qt: convert decimal to hex with 4 Bytes

Tags: qt, type-conversion, hex

I am using Qt to convert a decimal into a hex string

```
QString hexvalue = QString("%1").arg(decimal, 8, 16, QLatin1Char( '0' ));
```

I want to have

> `1: 00 00 00 01`
>
> `-1: FF FF FF FF`

This code however results in

`FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF` and `00 00 00 01`

How can I limit this to 4 Bytes?

Comment: do you mean 1 is parsed to FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF????
 o0?

Comment: No -1 is output as `FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF`

Comment: Use `QString("%1").arg(ulong(decimal), 8, 16, QLatin1Char( '0' ))`

Comment: Why ulong (unsigned long) ? The code must work correct with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask with an AND operator to do this :

```
int val = -1;
qDebug() << QString("%1 : %2").arg(val).arg(val & 0xffffffff, 8, 16, QLatin1Char('0'));
```

will display

> "-1 : ffffffff"

**EDIT**

As requested in comments, here is one way to have a variable `length` in the range `0 < length <= 8`:

```
int mask = 0xffffffff >> (32 - 4 * length); // assuming a 32 bit integer
int val = -1;
qDebug() << QString("%1 : %2").arg(val).arg((unsigned int)(val & mask), length, 16, QLatin1Char('0'));
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I want the length (8) to be a variable?

Comment: assuming a 32 bit integer, then an ugly hack  would be `int mask = 0xffffffff >> (32 - 4 * length);` with 0 < length <= 8 plus a cast `(unsigned int)(val & mask)`.

Comment: Can you update the answer, so that it is obvious how to implement the comment in the code.